# Mono Slice with data transformation in spring reactive cassandra

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-data-cassandra

After reading the new spring data casandra documentation ([here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/reference/html/)), it says that there is now `Mono<Slice<T>>` support for reactive cassandra.
Which is great, because in my team, we wanted to implement some sort of pagination on our reactive response. So we are happy to move from `Flux<T>` to `Mono<Slice<T>>` but there is this issue, we do transformations on the data of our flux, with flux.map, but that doesn't seem possible with Slice without blocking.

For example, we have this functionallity:

```
Flux<Location> resp = repository.searchLocations(searchFields).map(this::transformLocation);
```

Where transformLocation is a function that receives the database object and returns a more user friendly object with more user friendly data.
How will you achieve that with `Mono<Slice<Location>>`?

From what I have seen of Slice, you can get the data with getContent, but that returns a list, will that not be like blocking?

Comment: How will it be blocking unless you block it intentionally? You can use that list and transform each of its objects and make flux from it and use that result like you were doing before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the list, got from the `getContent()` [method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Slice.html#getContent--), to create a flux as you were doing before.

```
Mono<Slice<Location>> sliceMono; //this is just another mono on which you can operate

Flux<location> intermediateResp = sliceMono.flatMap(slice -> Flux.fromIterable(slice.getContent()));

//you can now transform this intermediateResp flux as you were doing before, can't you?
```

Won't this serve your purpose or do you require something else?

(The code has been written without the help of IDE, so use it to understand the approach)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response, turns out you can just transform the elements of the slice the same way you transform the elements inside a flux, my problem was on another part of the code and I totally missed it. Thanks for the response anyway :)